# Multiple multicast channels on same machine- specify an address or use INADDR_ANY?

Tags: c, linux, network-programming, udp, multicast

Below is basic code to create a multicast socket on Linux.

I have multiple processes running the below code on one machine, each listening to a different multicast channel. Only the relevant data should be processed by each process.

Two stages in the code require an address, or `INADDR_ANY`.

Given I will have multiple **separate** multicast channels running, I'm unsure when I should use `INADDR_ANY` or specify the address. I don't want a process receiving the wrong multicast data.

```
// Create socket
int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(yes));

// Create multicast group
sockaddr_in mcast_group
memset(&mcast_group, 0, sizeof(mcast_group));
mcast_group.sin_family = AF_INET;
mcast_group.sin_port = htons(mcastPort);
mcast_group.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;                         // INADDR_ANY or  specific address?

// Bind socket to multicast group
bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&mcast_group, sizeof(mcast_group));

// Tell Kernel to join multicast group
struct ip_mreq mreq;
mreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr(group.c_str());
mreq.imr_interface.s_addr = inet_addr(interface.c_str());         // INADDR_ANY or specific address?

setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, &mreq, sizeof(mreq));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each socket is listening *only* for multicast packets and not unicast, and only for a single multicast address, you can bind directly to the multicast address:

```
sockaddr_in mcast_group;
memset(&mcast_group, 0, sizeof(mcast_group));
mcast_group.sin_family = AF_INET;
mcast_group.sin_port = htons(mcastPort);
mcast_group.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(group.c_str());  // bind to multicast group

bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&mcast_group, sizeof(mcast_group));
```

Note that you'll still have to join the multicast group.

Comment: And leave the address (when telling the Kernel to join the multicast) as INADDR_ANY?

What is the difference between these two addresses?

Comment: @user997112 Joining the multicast group doesn't change.  You only need to change the bind address.

Answer (score 1):

bind to INADDR_ANY will receive unicast as well as multicast packets. bind to the multicast address will only receive the multicast packets. THIS IS the different between Linux socket and Windows socket programming for multicast receiving.